# Problema con condicional al buscar archivos con Python

Tags: python, condiciones

Mi codigo lo que hace es buscar los nombres de los archivos que esten en un archivo de excel, si los encuentra los copia a otra ruta, y aqui esta el problema, si no lo encuentra no hace nada, y no se como hacer para ponerle que diga una lista de los archivos que no encontro.

```
    import os, shutil, xlrd

#creamos una lista vacia para almacenar los codigos posteriormente
files_to_find = []
ruta_destino = 'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4' #'input("Digite la ruta de la carpeta destino: ")

#Abrimos el archivo excel y cargamos todos los codigos en la lista vacia.
data = xlrd.open_workbook(input("Digite el nombre del archivo excel y su extension: "))
sheet1 = data.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(sheet1.nrows):
    files_to_find.append(sheet1.cell_value(i, 0))
    
#Buscamos los codigos en esta ruta
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Desktop/FOTOS PRODUCTOS/'):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            
            # Si lo encontramos nos dira que fue encontrado en esta ruta
            print ('Encontrado en esta ruta: ' + str(root))
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), 'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4')
```

Comment: Crea una lista  y agrega los nombres de archivo a esa lista. Luego puedes hacer `print("\n".join(archivos_no_encontrados))` y eso te mostrará los path de los archivos linea por linea.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre la solucion, cree una nueva lista y la llene con los nombres de los archivos donde buscaria, luego le hice iteracion y le aplique la condicional:

```
import os, shutil, xlrd

#creamos una lista vacia para almacenar los codigos posteriormente
files_to_find = []
lista_imagenes_total=[]
ruta_destino = 'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4' #'input("Digite la ruta de la carpeta destino: ")

#Abrimos el archivo excel y cargamos todos los codigos en la lista vacia.
data = xlrd.open_workbook(input("Digite el nombre del archivo excel y su extension: "))
sheet1 = data.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(sheet1.nrows):
    files_to_find.append(sheet1.cell_value(i, 0))
    
#Buscamos los codigos en esta ruta
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Desktop/FOTOS PRODUCTOS/'):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            print (f'{_file} Encontrado en esta ruta: ' + str(root)) # Si lo encontramos nos dira que fue encontrado en esta ruta
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), 'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4')
        lista_imagenes_total.append(_file)

#Verificamos cuales archivos no fueron encontrados y lo imprimimos
for elementos in files_to_find:
    if elementos not in lista_imagenes_total:
        print(f"El archivo {elementos} no fue encontrado!")
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es usar un diccionario en lugar de una lista. Este tendrá por llave el nombre del archivo. Inicialmente tendrá el valor `False` ("no encontrado").

Luego, al recorrer el directorio, cada vez que encuentres un archivo, cambiaras la entrada en el diccionario a `True` ("encontrado").

Al final recorres el diccionario extrayendo todas las llaves con valor `False`.

#### Demo

Teniendo está estructura de subdirectorios y archivos

```
.
./dir4
./dir4/arch4
./dir4/arch3
./dir1
./dir1/arch1
./dir3
./dir2
./dir2/arch2
```

queremos buscar los archivos `arch1` hasta `arch5`. Este último no existe.

```
import os

files_to_find = {"arch1": False, "arch2": False, "arch3": False, "arch4": False, "arch5": False}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('walk/'):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            # Si lo encontramos nos dira que fue encontrado en esta ruta
            files_to_find[_file] = True
            print('Encontrado en esta ruta: ' + str(root))

no_encontrado = [llave for llave, valor in files_to_find.items() if valor is False]
print("No encontrados:", no_encontrado)
```

produce:

```
Encontrado en esta ruta: walk/dir4
Encontrado en esta ruta: walk/dir4
Encontrado en esta ruta: walk/dir1
Encontrado en esta ruta: walk/dir2
No encontrados: ['arch5']

Process finished with exit code 0
```